# undefined reference to `libintl_gettext' with MinGW/MSYS and CMake

Tags: c++, windows, gettext, mingw32, msys

I am trying to add gettext to a C++ project. It compiles and runs fine under Linux, but I get a linker error with MinGW32 in Windows 7 64 bit. I am compiling with `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..`, because MinGW doesn't work for soe nebulous reason. I also tried ninja.

In the `CMakeLists.txt`, I have

```
find_package(Gettext REQUIRED
include_directories(${GETTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR})
if (INTL_FOUND)
    find_package(INTL REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${INTL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

Which is found as

```
 GETTEXT_INCLUDE_DIR = C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include
```

The project is compiling without problems, but then in the linking stage, I get the following errors:

```
<source file location> undefined reference to `libintl_gettext'
<source file location> undefined reference to `libintl_setlocale'
<source file location> undefined reference to `libintl_textdomain'
```

etc.

I had a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/FAQ.html#integrating_undefined

and added the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-s -O2 -lintl")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lintl")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}
```

then I tried

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-s -O2 -lintl -liconv -LC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lintl -liconv -LC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib -IC:/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/include")
```

which also didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Win-builds and I am having a similar problem.
I am only trying to build a Hello World program using gettext.

From what I understand, this should work but does not:

```
gcc -lintl.dll -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o testGettex.exe testGettex.c
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o:testGettex.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `libintl_setlocale'
C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o:testGettex.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `libintl_setlocale'
C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o:testGettex.c:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `libintl_bindtextdomain'
C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o:testGettex.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `libintl_textdomain'
C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o:testGettex.c:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `libintl_gettext'
C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o:testGettex.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `__printf__'
d:/prog/win-builds/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Julien\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAvCaR2.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
d:/prog/win-builds/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I tried to link directly using the `.dll` instead of using the `.dll.a`, and I could build with this command:

```
gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o testGettex.exe D:\Prog\Win-builds\bin\libintl-8.dll testGettex.c
```

However, I don't know how you can tell to CMake to link directly to `.dll`... Maybe the best to do would be to fing MinGW's bug tracker and to explain them the problem with the file `libintl.dll.a`.

Edit: I just read the link you give and I saw another solution who also worked, moving the two -l options to the end of command

```
gcc -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=gnu99 -o testGettex.exe testGettex.c -lintl.dll -liconv
```

Maybe there could be a way to tell CMake to move the two options at end of line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My situation was a bit different – I am building `pacman` on MSYS2 (Cygwin clone) using Meson+Ninja. Here in Ninja recipe the POSIX-like libs are indicated directly, using their full path names (while WinAPI libs goes by using `-l...` notation). In my case I inserted this into the middle of the command line: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.3.0/../../../../lib/libintl.dll.a` (which I copied from the other command line which succeeded). The real path `/usr/lib/libintl.dll.a` works too. Cheers!